# Data is retrieved from Firebase only once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on Android Studio and I have an activity that retrieves data (latitude and longitude) with a button hit from firebase after typing an ID in a textBox, it retrieves related data to that Id. The problem is with the second try, when I enter a different ID, nothing happens and it doesn’t retrieve data anymore. It does it once. So how can I make it keeps retrieving and accessing firebase with every button hit?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I have solved it, your comment on the first answer was a hint, I noticed that I was sending Firebase wrong value. It should be a variable value every time so that I can receive different result, but I was sending a fixed value.

Comment: No problem, I have added the answer if you want to check it as correct, any question feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be in your EditText because you are not sending the new ID to retrieve the data, maybe you need to empty it first and re send the query.

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in a Firebase Realtime Database is retrieved by invoking a blocking method on a database reference, which returns the data stored at the reference. Each method call is a onetime operation. That means the SDK does not register any callbacks that listen to subsequent data updates. This model of data retrieval is supported in Python and Go Admin SDKs.

Comment: So that no way to do it in Android Studio?

Comment: You can still attach listeners that will keep listening to data changes on a certain reference, and also you can fetch one time to a reference and detach the listener. I think the problem might be in the editText that is not setting up the new ID to be retrieved

Answer (score 0):

you might using 
    **addListenerForSingleValueEvent(**) inside the code,you can
change it to
**addValueEventListener()**